# Process Silverfast color raw scans in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, scanning, presets

In SilverFast there are two main scan modes. One called raw which export a DNG file and one TIFF. In the DNG format I need to invert  as part of the post process in Lightroom. Or I can go for TIFF format and let SilverFast do the 'magic'. I would prefer scanning in DNG format but i am not sure how I can best invert a color negative. Any advise?

Comment: Your question is unclear : is it a scanning or a Lightroom issue ? Lightroom can't "scan", it only knows how to import pictures.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I rewrote my question in the hope it clarifies what I am looking for.

Comment: OK, now if your question is "how inverting color of a PNG scan ?" It may be a partial duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19846/i-have-scanned-a-film-negative-how-do-i-adjust-the-color-using-software

Comment: How to invert : http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41026/is-there-any-good-method-to-invert-a-negative-image-duplicated-with-a-digital-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has two parts and each part has already be answered (at least partially). With a DNG image out of the scanner, you will have to invert the color. Then, regardless of the image format (DNG or TIFF), you will maybe observe a color cast.

**How to invert color in Lightroom**

You can have a look at this post : [Is there any good method to invert a negative image (duplicated with a digital camera) in Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41026/is-there-any-good-method-to-invert-a-negative-image-duplicated-with-a-digital-c)

Using Lightroom, go the Tone Curve adjustement section. Make sure **Linear** is selected (Point Curve) and that you are using the **Channel RGB**. Now invert the curve by moving the two extremes points.

[image: Original Picture]

[image: Inverted Picture]

**How to adjust the color**

Have a look at this question : [I have scanned a film negative - how do I adjust the color using software?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19846/i-have-scanned-a-film-negative-how-do-i-adjust-the-color-using-software)

If your inverted image has a color cast, the easiest way to correct it is by setting a neutral (gray) spot in the White Balance Selector.